# Extract url data and image with php or Ajax or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i've a html message box in my website. So how do i get content and image after given any  url to the message box. (Like facebook post box)

Ex: http://www.bdnews24.com/details.php?cid=2&id=221107&hb=5. say this is the url. If i write this url to the message box then it's should get all the content and image to my website.

How do i do this with PHP.

Any idea or website link
Thank\s a lot!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

There is many example and explanation of function : [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)